# In what order does cat choose files to display?

Tags: unix, cat

I have the following line in a bash script:

```
find . -name "paramsFile.*" | xargs -n131072 cat > parameters.txt
```

I need to make sure the order the files are concatenated in does not change when I use this command. For example, if I run this command twice on the same set of paramsFile.*, parameters.txt should be the same both times. My question is, is this the case? And if it isn't, how can I make sure it is?

Thanks!

Edit: the same question goes for xargs: would that change how the files are fed to cat?

Edit2: as William Pursell pointed out, this question is actually about find. Does find always return files in the same order?

Comment: Your question is not about `cat` or `xargs`.  You need to question whether or not `find` will always output the files in the same order.

Comment: You are indeed correct sir. Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: I see nothing in the standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) that requires it to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From description in `man cat`:

> The cat utility reads files sequentially, writing them to the standard
>   output.  **The file operands are processed in command-line order.**
>        If file is a single dash (`-') or absent, cat reads from the standard input.  If file is a UNIX domain socket, cat connects to it
>   and
>        then reads it until EOF.  This complements the UNIX domain binding capability available in inetd(8).

So yes as long as you pass the files to `cat` in the same order every time you'll be ok.

Comment: Thanks! I figured that was the case, but what about xargs? Could that change the order?

Comment: Yea no problem, I believe xargs will just read whatever string(s) are passed to it sequentially. You shouldn't have anything to worry about. Can I get an 'answer accepted'?